# How to create a wrapper class around an enum with a dynamic field

Tags: java, android, enums, constructor, wrapper

I am currently working on an android project, where I use an enum to dynamically create URLs.

Depending on which `RequestOperation` is selected and passed to my `startRequest()` method, another API will be called, so for the mapping my old approach was to map over the enum values by a switch case and to return the according url part as string like so:

```
public enum RequestOperation {

    WORKERS,
    ERRORS_COMPACT,
    ERRORS_COMPLEX,
    ERROR_TAKE_OVER,
    SESSION_CHECK,
    SESSION_LOGIN,
    SESSION_LOGOUT;

    public String parsingKey() {
        switch (this) {
            case WORKERS:
                return "workers";
            case ERRORS_COMPACT:
                return "errors";
            case ERRORS_COMPLEX:
                return "errors";
            case ERROR_TAKE_OVER:
                return "take_over";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

    public String apiURL(ArrayList<String> params) {
        switch (this) {
            case WORKERS:
                return "schedule.m";
            case ERRORS_COMPACT:
                return "errors.m?mode=compact";
            case ERRORS_COMPLEX:
                return "errors.m?mode=complex";
            case ERROR_TAKE_OVER:
                return "assign_task.m?param0=" + params.get(0) + "&param1=" + params.get(1);
            case SESSION_CHECK:
                return "desk.m?do=check&param0=" + params.get(0);
            case SESSION_LOGIN:
                return "desk.m?do=login&param0=" + params.get(0) + "&param1=" + params.get(1) + "&param2=" + params.get(2);
            case SESSION_LOGOUT:
                return "desk.m?do=logout&param0=" + params.get(0);
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, the composing of the url strings is very crude coded and I'm not confident with that. To find a method for creating those I tried to create a wrapper class around the enum:

```
public class RequestOperation {

    public enum Type {
        WORKERS("workers", "workers.m"),
        ERRORS_COMPACT("errors", "errors.m?mode=compact"),
        ERRORS_COMPLEX("errors", "errors.m?mode=complex"),

        //here's where im stuck, cause the second string is not the complete url
        ERROR_TAKE_OVER("take_over", "assign_task.m?param0="),
        SESSION_CHECK("", "desk.m?do=check&dparam0="),
        SESSION_LOGIN("", "desk.m?do=login&param0="),
        SESSION_LOGOUT("", "desk.m?do=logout&param0=");

        //maybe pass the params in here some how, and compose the url selectively
        Type(String parsingKey, String applicationUrl) {
            this.parsing_key = parsingKey;
            this.application_url = applicationUrl;
        }

        //maybe move them out of the enum
        private String parsing_key;
        private String application_url;
        //private ArrayList<String> url_params = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private Type type;

    //expect parameters from the creator here maybe
    public RequestOperation(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String parsingKey() {
        return type.parsing_key;
    }

    public String application_url() {
        return type.application_url;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, i don't have any idea, how pass there params to the `RequestOperation` object, so that the `application_url` gets composed correctly. My first thought is, to overload the constructor of `Type`, so I can pass up to 3 more strings that will be filled in the gaps like in the first exhibit. Is there any way to do that ans is it furthermore a good practice?

Comment: you don't need a wrapper to add fields to an enum, you can add those to the enum itself.

Comment: There are no dynamic fields here.

Comment: ok, how can I pass the needed params properly then, so the url gets composed correctly? - will edit my post to make the question more clear

Comment: @procra you're not supposed to edit or dynamically set values of an enum. that's the whole point. they are (supposed to be) predefined

Comment: Yeah, that's why I moved away from the pure enum to the wrapper, that maybe will hold the properties, that are partially preset by the enum type, where it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use parameters like `?param0=` in enum declaration, but instead, keep raw urls in your enum.

For example this enum constant:

```
 ERROR_TAKE_OVER("take_over", "assign_task.m?param0=")
```

change to:

```
ERROR_TAKE_OVER("take_over", "assign_task.m")
```

and your `apiURL(String...)` could look like this:

```
public String apiURL(String... params) {
    if(params.length == 0) return type.application_url;
    return type.application_url 
        + "?" 
        + IntStream.range(0, params.length)
                   .mapToObj(i -> String.format("param%d=%s", i, params[i]))
                   .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
```

}

and let the webservlet handle possible parameter absence.

Example:

```
RequestOperation request = new RequestOperation(RequestOperation.Type.ERROR_TAKE_OVER);
System.out.println(request.apiURL()); //"assign_task.m"
System.out.println(request.apiURL("a")); //"assign_task.m?param0=a"
System.out.println(request.apiURL("a", "b", "c")); //"assign_task.m?param0=a&param1=b&param2=c"
```

Comment: that sounds like a well structured approach to me, will try that out

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution but just a work around. Ideally, an `enum` is supposed to store **constant** values and not dynamic one. In your case, the workaround would be to use `MessageFormat#format()`. The `application_url` value in `enum` would contain string with placeholders as:

```
SESSION_LOGIN("", "desk.m?do=login&param0={0}&param1={1}")
```

Note the use of `{}` as placeholder.

Now create a method that would form the URL based on the passed parameters as:

```
public String getApiUrl(String... params) {
    return MessageFormat.format(this.application_url, params);
}
```

Beware that this is a very crude way of doing what you are attempting to achieve as it has no checks over what or how many parameters could be passed.